# Double square brackets vs single square bracket in functions or for loops

Tags: r, function

So I know that double brackets return the element only while single brackets return a list with that  element inside.
But how does this  matter functionally when making functions or for loops?

Say I have a set of X and Y values, and want to find the best slope and y intersect for them. I have a list of x and y values ( stored in **data1**) and a list of  yintersect and slope values (stored in **parameters**).

I want to see which set of y-intersect and slope values comes closest to the actual Y values. So first I will make a function which outputs the y value GIVEN a set of yintersect and slope values from the parameters list.  This function is showed below titled **modelling_function**

```
parameters <- list(yintersect = c(1:10), slope = c(5:14))

data1 <- list(x = sample(100, 10), y = sample(200:10))

modelling_function <- function(parameters, data1) { 
parameters[[1]]+ parameters[[2]] * data1$x}
```

So two questions...

1. What is the difference between using single and double brackets here?
2. Why when I run this function do I only get 10 values? I would expect to get 10 * 10 = 100 values, because for each x value, there are 10 combinations of slope and intersect to be used.

I know im missing something here, I think related to what exactly is being done to each vector/list. I hope the brackets and knowing what is being done to each subsetted list  will help me figure that out.

Comment: Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el ?

Comment: Try it: with one bracket, `Error in parameters[2] * data1$x : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator`. This is because `parameters[2]` is a list, not a numeric vector.

Comment: for your data1 and parameters you will get vector of length 10 beacause parameters$yintersect and parameters$slope have length 10 and data1$x has length 10

Answer (score 1):

`[[` is used to subset only one element from a vector and it peels off the outer structure if the vector is a list:

```
a <- list(1:3, c("a", "b", "c"), 100:107)
a[[1]]

[1] 1 2 3
```

Note that `a[[1]]` is not a list but an integer vector (you can imagine that you [draw from the] list by taking an element from [the corresponding] position in that list).

```
a[1]

[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3
```

Note that `[` is keeping the structure, `a[1]` returns a subset of the vector -- in this case its a list with 1 element. With `[` you can subset more than 1 element:

```
a[c(1,3)]

[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107
```

You can use `[[` and `[` on other vector types. But because there is no outer structure to peel off, they will return same value when subsetting 1 element of the vector.

```
x <- 1:10

x[[1]]
[1] 1

x[1]
[1] 1

x[c(1,3)]
[1] 1 3
```